# An editor to add the content of a PDF file to another PDF

Tags: windows, pdf, images, pdf-editor

I'm looking for a tool that allows me to delete an image in a PDF file and replace it with a picture in a PDF format. I don't want to merge two PDF files.

Adobe Acrobat Pro XI can remove an image and add an image in JPG, TIFF etc. but it cannot add the content of a PDF file. I tried also Nitro PDF 9. I cannot do that, either. I don't know whether Adobe Acrobat DC can do that or the next version of Nitro PDF.

So, can anyone recommend a free (preferably) tool or paid (preferably trial but I can buy software)? The tool must run of Windows 7.

Comment: What stops you from converting the pdf image to a jpg and do what you described using Adobe Acrobat Pro XI?

Comment: @DimP I guess the fact that a PDF might also include vector elements.

Comment: Yes, it's about preserving vector elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master PDF Editor can do that. A trial is available for Windows. Price is reasonable at $50 USD.
https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor
Well, it doesn't insert a PDF image directly, but it can copy an image from one PDF into another, including vectors.

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for!